# Creating in panel TOC widget using Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS developer edition?

Tags: arcgis-online, api, dojo, widget, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm trying to create a custom widget, in web AppBuilder for developers, for my web application that will be a TOC. Does anyone have a code already produced for this or know how to adapt code to do this? Right now I am using this (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=98d9e760d6d1496487ca583b0e8ce73c) as a base but I don't know how to change it to create a widget.

Comment: I would look under the GeoNet community here: https://geonet.esri.com/groups/web-app-builder-custom-widgets/content